# TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'numpy.float64'

Tags: python

I don't understand how to fix the error in this case. I've already tried with numpy array, but the problem still presents.

What I'm trying to do is: to calculate the runge function with the x for n iterations. For making this, I think that I have do put every single x in a list, and I do this with the `fill_cheby` function. After this, I want to use the numbers in `list1` as arguments of lagrange function in `runge_interpolate`. The problem is that I don't know how to append the elements in `list1`. Here the code and the complete traceback:

```
def fill_cheby(list1,n,x):
    if n==0:
        return n, x
    else:
        for i in range(0,n):
            x=np.cos(((2*(n-i)+1)*3.14)/(2*(n+1)))
            list1.append(x)

        return list1

def runge_interpolate(n):
    p=lagrange(list1, runge(x))
    print("Il polinomio è ", p)
    return x, p

list1=[]

n=5
x=0
fill_cheby(list1,n,x)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "arraycheby.py", line 33, in <module>
  fill_cheby(list,n,x)
File "arraycheby.py", line 19, in fill_cheby
  list1.append(x)
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'numpy.float64'
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin `list` type

Comment: Please add the full traceback of the exception. You really don't want to use the name `list`, that masks the built-in name. Also, `x=list` would not create a copy, if that's what you expected to happen.

Comment: Also, if this question is about the `fill_cheby()` function, then the `runge_interpolate` and `runge` functions can be removed from the question, together with most of your imports.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm sorry but I'm new to Python; I've modified the code following your suggestions, but now I've this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arraycheby.py", line 33, in <module>
    fill_cheby(list,n,x)
  File "arraycheby.py", line 19, in fill_cheby
    list1.append(x)
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'numpy.float64'

Comment: @Frank you can edit your question directly, rather than trying to put code in comments

Comment: Exactly, C.Nivs, is the runge function.